# evaluating a boolean against a bit field in LINQ To SQL query

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

I am trying to do a simple little LINQ To SQL query against a SQL CE database.

```
var result = from item in items
             where item.IsTrue == true
             select item;
```

The problem is that the `IsTrue` property is a `bit` field in the database (`bool` in the CLR).  When it goes to SQL in CE I get `SELECT ... WHERE ([t0].IsTrue = 1)..`  The 1 value is an integer to SqlCe and it wont cast it by default.

The index that I have on that column (the IsTrue column) doesn't get used.  Instead it tries to cast all of the `istrue` values in the database to integers and compares them to the 1.

How can I get LINQ To SQL to generate `WHERE ([t0].IsTrue = Cast(1 as bit))...`? I need somehow to force the casting of that value to a `bit`, and thereby allowing use of the index?

I tried:

- `item.IsTrue == Convert.ToBoolean(1)`
- `item.IsTrue == Convert.ToBoolean("true")`
- `item.IsTrue == (bool)true)`

Hoping to get the expression tree to have a cast in it so that it converts to a cast in LINQ To SQL, but i cant seem to find a way.  Any ideas?

Comment: I know it's 6 years later, but Entity Framework is doing the casting to bit now.  At least it is for me.

Answer (score 4):

I landed on this page because I had the same problem.

I found you can work around this particular brokenness by using compiled queries.  To use your example:

```
DataContext context = /* ... */;

Func <DataContext, IQueryable<ItemType> compiledQuery = null;

compiledQuery = CompiledQuery.Compile(
   (DataContext ctx) => (from item in Items
                         where item.IsTrue
                         select item)
);

var result = compiledQuery(context);
```

If you look at the SQL this generates (by hooking up the log stream in the `DataContext`) it  for some reason does the right thing where using non-compiled queries does not.  Your indices that have `bool`s in them will start working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried leaving out the `== true` part and just using

`var result = from item in items where item.IsTrue select item;`

Alternatively, using [method syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx):

`var result = items.Where(item => item.IsTrue);`

Comment: Yes I tried that as well, but it still added the " = 1" to the sql.